# Force close - LayoutInflater

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

Here is my code for a file , which aims to dynamically add views using a Layout

I'm referring to http://maxmakedesign.co.uk/how-to/80/android-add-views-in-a-loop

```
package com.example.database;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Dynamic extends Activity 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dynamic);



String[] info = new String[2];
info[0] = "info 1";
info[1] = "info 2";

LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout insertPoint = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.insert_point);
List views = new ArrayList();

for(int i1=0; i1 < info.length; i1++)
{
    View view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_dynamic, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.a_text_view);
    textView.setText(info[0]);  /* if I comment this out , no force close */

    //views.add(view);
}
/*
for(int i = 0; i< views.size(); i++)
{
    insertPoint.addView((View) views.get(i));
}*/







}

}
```

If I comment out "textView.setText(info[0]);" I don't get a force close.However , with it , I do.I'd like to know why ?

Here's my Logcat text :

```
> 03-07 21:26:04.880: E/Trace(20025): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-07 21:26:05.681: D/libEGL(20025): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
03-07 21:26:05.691: D/libEGL(20025): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
03-07 21:26:05.701: D/libEGL(20025): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
03-07 21:26:05.711: I/Adreno200-EGL(20025): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:294>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB.04.01.01.00.036_msm8960_JB_CL2644550_release_AU (CL2644550)
03-07 21:26:05.711: I/Adreno200-EGL(20025): Build Date: 07/31/12 Tue
03-07 21:26:05.711: I/Adreno200-EGL(20025): Local Branch: 
03-07 21:26:05.711: I/Adreno200-EGL(20025): Remote Branch: quic/master
03-07 21:26:05.711: I/Adreno200-EGL(20025): Local Patches: NONE
03-07 21:26:05.711: I/Adreno200-EGL(20025): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB.04.01.01.00.036 +  NOTHING
03-07 21:26:05.771: D/OpenGLRenderer(20025): Enabling debug mode 0
03-07 21:27:38.542: E/Trace(20165): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-07 21:27:38.952: D/AndroidRuntime(20165): Shutting down VM
03-07 21:27:38.952: W/dalvikvm(20165): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bf3300)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database/com.example.database.Dynamic}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2190)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4978)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at com.example.database.Dynamic.onCreate(Dynamic.java:48)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-07 21:27:38.952: E/AndroidRuntime(20165):    ... 11 more
03-07 21:27:40.253: I/Process(20165): Sending signal. PID: 20165 SIG: 9
03-07 21:32:47.353: E/Trace(20649): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-07 21:32:47.613: D/AndroidRuntime(20649): Shutting down VM
03-07 21:32:47.613: W/dalvikvm(20649): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bf3300)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database/com.example.database.Dynamic}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2190)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4978)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    at com.example.database.Dynamic.onCreate(Dynamic.java:48)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-07 21:32:47.613: E/AndroidRuntime(20649):    ... 11 more
03-07 21:32:49.075: I/Process(20649): Sending signal. PID: 20649 SIG: 9
```

The contents of activity_dynamic.xml are :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/insert_point"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:text="Add View" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you need to add an `TextView` in `activity_dynamic` layout with id `a_text_view`. add an TextView in `activity_dynamic` layout as :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/insert_point"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:text="Add View" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/a_text_view"  <!-- TextView id here -->
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    <!-- other TextView Attributes... -->

   />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks a ton.However , I have a question - why does the TextView with id a_text_view need to necessarily be inside activity_dynamic.xml ?
Could it not be in another XML file ? Or is it because we are using activity_dynamic.xml in setContentView()

Thanks

Comment: @Anant : good question. problem is you are trying to find an TextView inside activity_dynamic xml which is not exist . when u inflate any xml layout as  `View view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_dynamic, null);` it means u can access any view from `activity_dynamic` using view instance